# Renaming all existing attributes in an array of Json objects

Tags: postgresql

I work with  Postgres db.

For example - there is a table

```
CREATE TABLE public.json_objects(id serial primary key, objects text);
```

it stores such an arrays of json

```
INSERT INTO public.json_objects (objects) VALUES ('[{"name":"Ivan"}]'), ('[{"name":"Petr"}, "surname":"Petrov"}]'), ('[{"form":"OOO"}, {"city":"Kizema"}]');
```

How can I replace the attribute "name"  with "first name" or "surname" with "second name" everywhere?

I am using update with the select - subquery.
In this case, a replacement will occur, but if the attribute does not exist in the json object, then it will be added to the json with a null value (and this should not be)

```
WITH updated_table AS (SELECT id, jsonb_agg(new_field_json) as new_fields_json 
FROM (SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(json_objects.objects::jsonb) - 'name' || jsonb_build_object('first name', jsonb_array_elements(json_objects.objects::jsonb) -> 'name') new_field_json FROM public.json_objects) r group by id) UPDATE public.json_objects SET objects = updated_table.new_fields_json FROM updated_table where json_objects.id = updated_table.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a single operation, so you can just use the `regexp_replace` function to replace the key

```
update table_1 set objects = regexp_replace(objects, '(\"name"+)', '"first name"');
update table_1 set objects = regexp_replace(objects, '(\"surname"+)', '"second name"')
```

Demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=43a963f1e8420856afd1e4d4af530f8b)

Comment: This only works if the key and value are different everywhere. I only need to rename the keys

Comment: agree with @user19296905. addtionally regexp_replace expects a text input as first argument. you would need to cast it first.

`update table_1 set objects = regexp_replace(objects::text, '(\"name"+)', '"first name"')::json;`